# fancy radio buttons in css

Tags: html, css

CSS rooking here. I had a previous version of this working when the source I was dealing with changed the code that generates the field styling. Now I'm stuck.

Here is my styling:

```
#button-left {
float: left;
}

#button-right {
float: left;
}

#button-left label input {
display: none;
}

#button-left label input:checked {
background-color:red;
}

#button-left label {
background-color: #1e73be;
border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
color: #ffffff !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
padding: 5px 10px;
}

#button-left label:hover {
background-color: #0066bf;
color: #ffffff !important;
}

#button-right label input {
display: none;
}

#button-right label {
background-color: #1e73be;
border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
color: #ffffff !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
padding: 5px 10px;
}

#button-right label:hover {
background-color: #0066bf;
color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Here is the html I'm dealing with:

```
<div id="button-left"><div class="frm_radio"><label for="field_465-0"><input type="radio" checked="checked" value="Option 1" id="field_465-0" name="item_meta[465]">Option 1</label></div></div>
```

Styling for ID button-right is pretty much the exact same thing.

I can't work with the three digit numbered ID's or Names (IE: field.... item_meta...). I also can't work with JQuery. This needs to be more of a straight CSS/HTML only oriented solution. I want the "fancy buttons" to change to another background color when selected. How can I go about making this work the way I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input fields must be outside and immediately after the label, then you can use an adjacent sibling selector like:

```
input:checked + label{
  /* checked styles */
}
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
label {
  background-color: #1e73be;
  border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
label:hover {
  background-color: #0066bf;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="Option 1" id="field_465-0" name="item_meta[465]" />
<label for="field_465-0">
  Option 1
</label>

<input type="radio" value="Option 2" id="field_465-1" name="item_meta[465]" />
<label for="field_465-1">
  Option 1
</label>
```

---

> *...It has to be inside the label.*

Then you can put a "span" element in the label too, and apply the checked styles on `label input:checked + span`

```css
label input {
  display: none;
}
label input:checked + span{
  background-color: red;
}
label span{
  background-color: #1e73be;
  border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
label:hover span{
  background-color: #0066bf;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="Option 1" name="item_meta[465]" />
  <span> Option 1 </span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" value="Option 2" name="item_meta[465]" />    
  <span> Option 2 </span>
</label>
```

An advantage of this method is that you don't need IDs/fors anymore

Comment: It isn't possible for the code to be after the input code. It has to be inside the label.

Comment: That works, but I will continue to use IDs/fors because it isn't a global thing, it's specific as I define it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe you'll need to use a little bit of javascript to make this work (which doesn't really apply to your CSS/HTML only solution).

All you really need to do however is to use the "onclick" function of javascript to change the style of the element in question (in this case, your fancy buttons).

```
<div id="example" style="style1" onclick="document.getElementById('example').setAttribute("class", "style2");" />
```

Comment: I don't think this will revert back to the original style when it is clicked again (i.e. deselected).